# JavaScript currency conversion with openexchangerates.org

Tags: javascript, jquery, money.js

I have a site that will feature multiple prices on any particular page. Within the header I have placed a select field that has a few currency options.

All the on page prices all sit within div the the `.prices` class. I'd like to be able to switch these prices dynamically to match the selected option. Each price will always be stored in GBP in the database so I am always trying to convert from that as a base value.

I am storing the selected option as a `localstorage` item, please let me know if there is a better way to do it. This then maintains the user experience across the site.

I am using `money.js`, http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js and https://openexchangerates.org to do the conversion but I think I am missing a step, or maybe more.

The HTML is pretty simple:

```
<select name="currency-conversion" id="currency-conversion">
  <option value="gbp">&#163;GBP</option>
  <option value="usd">&#36;USD</option>
  <option value="eur">&#128;EUR</option>
  <option value="cny">&#22278;CNY</option>
  <option value="jpy">&#165;JPY</option>
  <option value="hkd">&#22291;HKD</option>
</select>
```

The JS so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  // Currency
  $.getJSON(
    // NB: using Open Exchange Rates here, but you can use any source!
    'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=#################',
    function(data) {
      // Check money.js has finished loading:
      if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
        fx.rates = data.rates;
        fx.base = data.base;
      } else {
        // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
        var fxSetup = {
          rates : data.rates,
          base : data.base
        }
      }
    }
  );

  if (localStorage.getItem("currency") === null) {
  } else {
    $('#currency-conversion').val(localStorage.currency);
  }


  $(document).on("change","select",function(){
    var currency = this.value;
    $("option[value=" + this.value + "]", this)
    .attr("selected", true).siblings()
    .removeAttr("selected")
    localStorage.setItem('currency', currency);
  });

  $("#currency-conversion").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    console.log(selectedCountry);
    update_prices(selectedCountry);
  });

  function update_prices(selectedCountry) {
    fx.base = GBP;
  }
});
```

Do I need to use my `update_prices()` function to simply update the `.prices` divs? I know I'm not understanding the link I need to make to use the `openexchangerates.org` call, and I've been staring at this for a few hours now.  `money.js` has a nice call that I think I could use to update the `.price` divs which is `.convert()` but this missing stage with open exchange has got me stumped.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't even use those API's. It took me a while to find, but I think you'll like [this](https://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Format.aspx?rel=H10&series=60f32914ab61dfab590e0e470153e3ae&lastobs=10&from=&to=&filetype=csv&label=include&layout=seriescolumn&type=package). You can select the range you want then hit the **Go to download** button, which will take you to another page where you look under **Bookmark This** and you'll see **Direct download for automated systems**. Right click on **Direct download for automated systems** and **Copy Link Location**. No need to pay for an API!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SlackSlave but I need to have live prices. The API I've looked at seems to be free, certainly for the limited usage the site will have.